# Pandas dataframe cross-referenced query

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing an id column, a linked id column, and a value column. The linked id is "optional" and refers to a different row in the same dataframe (with -1 denoting no link). What I want to do is select rows that have a valid link where `value` is equal to `value` in the row given by the linked id:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0,1,2,3,4,5], "linkid": [-1,3,-1,0,5,-1], "value": [10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 50]})
print(df)

# should match row 1 (only): id 1 has value 20 and linkid 3 also has value 20  
# should not match 
matched = df.loc[df.value == df.loc[df.id == df.linkid].value]
# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

My attempt above results in an error. I suspect my attempt is pretty far from the mark but not sure how to proceed. I want to avoid loops for performance reasons. Any help gratefully received

I thought it was clear enough but as per the comment in the code, my required output in this example is row 1 from the original dataframe:

```
id  linkid  value
 1       3   20.0
```

Comment: your need select only rows where 'id' == 'linkid'? or your need some merge? can you show what output you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
new_df = df.merge(df[['id','value']].rename(columns={'id':'linkid'}),how='left',on="linkid")
new_df[new_df.value_x == new_df.value_y]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another column `value_link` for the column `linkid` that is the `value` of the `id == linkid` . As follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0,1,2,3,4,5], "linkid": [-1,3,-1,0,5,-1], "value": [10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 50]})
df['value_link'] = df.linkid.apply(lambda x: df[df['id'] == x].value.values[0] if x != -1 else np.nan)

matched = df[df.value == df.value_link]
```